# My bind events are not working when mouse button pressed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a simple program. There is a frame, and its background color needs to be changed when the mouse cursor enters it and return the color to what it was when it left it. The problem occurs if I have pressed the mouse button somewhere outside the widget and haven't released the button yet. In this case, when I try to enter and leave the frame, the color doesn't change because no bindings are working up until I release the button. How can I fix it?

Simple code example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

simple_wid = tk.Frame(width=400, height=400, bg='black')
simple_wid.grid(padx=100, pady=100)

simple_wid.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: simple_wid.configure(bg='grey20'))
simple_wid.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: simple_wid.configure(bg='black'))

root.mainloop()
```

Forgive me if this question has already been asked on this site, but I didn't find anything related to this problem.